# Cannot teleop turtlebot3 in gazebo with melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to control a `turtlebot3` in gazebo using ROS. I can do this without a problem in `Ubuntu 16` `ros kinetic` (gazebo 7).  But I cannot do the same thing with same commands in `Ubuntu 18` `ros melodic` (gazebo 9)

Here's the log shown from `roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch` in `ros melodic`

```
xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
started roslaunch server http://xxxxxx:45893/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.5
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3042]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 331250c0-acb1-11ea-af42-0c5b8f279a64
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3053]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [3056]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [3064]
process[spawn_urdf-4]: started with pid [3070]
[ INFO] [1591968766.435037191]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1591968766.435766509]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1591968766.484922295]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1591968766.485743143]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1591968766.762218392, 0.003000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1591968767.093444620, 0.168000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/XXXXX/.ros/log/331250c0-acb1-11ea-af42-0c5b8f279a64/spawn_urdf-4*.log
```

ROS topic list after launching this is as follows

```
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Here's the log from the same roslaunch in `ros kinetic` in which this works fine

```
started roslaunch server http://xxxxxx-l-l:41851/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [8166]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to a1193f98-acb1-11ea-8274-8c04ba099a14
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [8179]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [8187]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [8207]
process[spawn_urdf-4]: started with pid [8213]
[ INFO] [1591968950.965463454]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1591968950.965900805]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1591968950.978686441]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1591968950.979178680]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1591968951.385803403, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1591968951.738905171, 0.163000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1591968951.738957452, 0.163000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /)
[ INFO] [1591968951.740414014, 0.163000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ INFO] [1591968951.740771321, 0.163000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1591968951.833262130, 0.163000000]: Starting plugin DiffDrive(ns = //)
[ INFO] [1591968951.833336896, 0.163000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): <rosDebugLevel> = na
[ INFO] [1591968951.834254336, 0.163000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): <tf_prefix> = 
[ INFO] [1591968951.836164861, 0.163000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise joint_states
[ INFO] [1591968951.836952897, 0.163000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Try to subscribe to cmd_vel
[ INFO] [1591968951.840035635, 0.163000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Subscribe to cmd_vel
[ INFO] [1591968951.840746578, 0.163000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise odom on odom 
[ INFO] [1591968951.865549383, 0.185000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1591968951.925287635, 0.245000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/XXXXX/.ros/log/a1193f98-acb1-11ea-8274-8c04ba099a14/spawn_urdf-4*.log
```

And this is the ROS topic list

```
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/gazebo_gui/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo_gui/parameter_updates
/imu
/joint_states
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
```

It seems like ROS related stuff are not running properly in `Ubuntu 18` `ros melodic`. Am I doing anything wrong or what's the issue here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354768/cannot-teleop-turtlebot3-in-gazebo-with-melodic/) by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently I didn't have `ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-pkgs` installed. (And didn't have any error indicating that it was missing either)

---

Originally posted by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) with karma: 168 on 2020-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ngovanmao](https://answers.ros.org/users/56816/ngovanmao/) on 2020-07-20**:
Thank you. I also faced this problem as a newbie.